# PHP Failing to connect to Postgres on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, php, postgresql

I can connect to my database by running php via the bash:

```
php -r '$link=@pg_connect("host=fakehost.edu port=5432 dbname=db user=user password=totallynotthepassword");if($link){echo "connected";} else { echo "no dice";}'
```

This results in a very happy "connected"

However, when I have the exact same PHP in a file served by Apache and go to that page, I get a very sad: "no dice"

Here is the code from the php file:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
$link=@pg_connect("host=fakehost.edu port=5432 dbname=db user=user password=totallynotthepassword");if($link){echo "connected";} else { echo "no dice";}
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

I thought it had to do with the apache user, but i just tested the same code su'ed to that user and it connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was a security setting, which is fixed by running:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on
```

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37955681/pg-connect-php-script-works-from-command-line-but-not-from-web-page